# Need some clarification about jQuery objects that don't reside in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I was trying to use browser console to do some HTML code manipulation. In console, I input

```
s = $('<div><span>ddd</span></div>');
s.remove('span');
```

Be noted the jQuery object `s` is not in the DOM, it only lives in the console. It turns out the `span` isn't removed from `s`. On the other hand, if `<div><span>ddd</span></div>` was in HTML, the `span` will surely be removed.

This brings up a question that has been confusing me for a long time. If I understand right, using `$()`, I can turn many things into jQuery objects, even if they are not actually in the DOM. But what is the difference between this kind of jQuery objects and the those jQuery objects that are linked to some DOM elements? And in the above code, in order to actually remove the `span` and get an output as `<div></div>`, do I have to write it into DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are not using [`$.fn.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) properly. Correct way to remove child `span` is to find it first:

```
s = $('<div><span>ddd</span></div>');
s.find('span').remove();
```

When you provide a selector to `remove`, jQuery filters supplied collection by this selector. However, in your case there is nothing that can be filtered out, since clearly `div` is not `span`. So `s.remove('span');` removes nothing.